# C# HTTP Reader get values from JSON format

Tags: c#, json, httplistener

I have a C# application getting a string from an HTTP listener. The data is sent to my application in the JSON format, and I am trying to get the specific values.

Right now, I read the data sent to me using:

```
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
            var request = context.Request;
            string message;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream,
                                                 request.ContentEncoding))
            {
                message = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

The string message = {   "message": "I've been shot!",   "phoneNumber": "12345?",   "position": "???",   "anon": "???",   "job": "ambulance" }

How would I go about getting these specific values and setting a string equal to the message, phonenumber, position, etc. Instead of just using the reader.ReadToEnd()

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Netwonsoft.Json, you can create an anonymous type to use as a template, then use the type to create an object with friendly property names.  You even get intellisense!

Example of parsing your example object:

```
public static void Main()
{

    string input = @"{ ""message"": ""I've been shot!"", ""phoneNumber"": ""12345?"", ""position"": ""???"", ""anon"": ""???"", ""job"": ""ambulance"" }";
    var objectTemplate = new
    {
        message = "", 
        phoneNumber = "", 
        position = "", 
        anon = "", 
        job = ""
    };

    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(input, objectTemplate);

    Console.WriteLine(deserialized.message);
    Console.WriteLine(deserialized.phoneNumber);
    Console.WriteLine(deserialized.position);

}
```

Output:

```
I've been shot!
12345?
???
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pPdfEp)